# Strip wicket tags, but keep wicket attributes

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I'd like to strip special Wicket tags (e.g. wicket:panel, wicket:child, etc.) from the output in development mode, but keep the `wicket:id` attribute.

In the WebApplications `init` one can set `getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true);` thus removing the special tags and attributes.

Is it possible to extend / modify Wicket at some point to keep the attribute when stripSpecialTags is set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.
Please file a ticket for improvement at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep the `wicket:id` attribute? For testing/selenium? Then you can use the `DebugSettings::setComponentPathAttributeName` method to output the wicket component path, which is usable in selenium.

Comment: Basically it's my personal preference to look for the wicket:id attribute, when looking at the DOM while developing components. It's easier than "parsing" the Wicket path attribute. FYI: i had to get rid of the wicket:panel tags because they would eventually break CSS flexbox layout.